# How to display cards in a Card Game in Java and have them clickable for selection?

Tags: java

I am programming a game of cards in Java, and everything is going well, but I have come up with a problem regarding the user interface. There are 4 players (1 Human 3 AI) and 54 cards. I want to have each player's cards drawn into 4 directions on the screen (UP LEFT DOWN RIGHT) and basically have a `MouseListener` for human's cards ONLY in order to select a card before playing move (have the card move up a little bit so you know it has been selected) while the other players' cards have their backside drawn and don't need any Listener. I am doing absolute positioning and cards should show up like this: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAaad.png)

Currently I am extending a `JComponent` and testing drawings into the paintComponent method of it. As cards are placed and drawn on top of another, working with coordinates is impossible for me to imagine, and also since I have a class `Card` for cards, can't have the `Card` instance and the drawn image connected. A thought is to use `JLabel` for each human cards, add an `ImageIcon` to it as for card representation, and add a `MouseListener` for each label so mouse clicking is easily determined. But the problem is how to have them drawn and updated on each player move as it would automatically be done for the other players cards that are just drawn as images inside `paintComponent`. I did try to create and add JLabels to the component inside the `paintComponent` method but I've seen it is totally not recommended to do.
Do you have any suggestion on what idea should I follow?

Thank you and regards

Comment: Can you post your partial code where you need help?

Comment: *"can't have the Card instance and the drawn image connected"* - Why not?  The `Card`s represent the model, which the view is responsible for rendering. The view then would need to keep track of where each card is, I'd probably use a `Rectangle` as a basic option, mapping them together through a `Map`.  You can then use a `MouseListener` on the `JComponent` and test the if the mouse event occurred within a given card using `Rectangle#contains`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> can't have the Card instance and the drawn image connected

Why not?  Basically a `Card` is a state of data.  A `Hand` is just a collection of `Card`s.  These basically build up a concept of a model.  Where the data itself is separated from the view displaying it.

That means, for the most part, the view becomes dumb.  It just takes the model and renders it in some way, allowing the user to interact with it.

In your case, you could use a `Rectangle` to represent the physical card's bounds.  When clicked, you would iterate over the hand and test to see if the mouse was clicked within the bounds of each `Rectangle` (mapped back to a `Card`) using `Rectangle#contains`

Now, the following example is "very" basic. It only focuses on a single player's hand, but it should give you the idea from which you can drive the concept.

[image: Cards]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class SimpleCards {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SimpleCards();
    }

    public SimpleCards() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                Deck.INSTANCE.shuffle();
                List<Hand> players = new ArrayList<>(5);
                for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
                    players.add(new Hand());
                }

                for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
                    for (Hand hand : players) {
                        hand.add(Deck.INSTANCE.pop());
                    }
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new GamePane(players));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class Hand {

        private List<Card> cards;

        public Hand() {
            cards = new ArrayList<>(25);
        }

        public void add(Card card) {
            cards.add(card);
        }

        public int size() {
            return cards.size();
        }

        public Iterable<Card> cards() {
            return cards;
        }

        public Iterable<Card> reveresed() {
            List<Card> reversed = new ArrayList<>(cards);
            Collections.reverse(reversed);
            return reversed;
        }
    }

    public static class Card {

        private Suit suit;
        private Face face;

        public Card(Suit suit, Face face) {
            this.suit = suit;
            this.face = face;
        }

        public Suit getSuit() {
            return suit;
        }

        public Face getFace() {
            return face;
        }

    }

    public enum Deck {

        INSTANCE;

        private List<Card> cards;
        private List<Card> playDeck;

        private Deck() {
            cards = new ArrayList<>(52);
            for (Suit suit : Suit.items) {
                for (Face face : Face.items) {
                    cards.add(new Card(suit, face));
                }
            }
            playDeck = new ArrayList<>(cards);
        }

        public void shuffle() {
            playDeck.clear();
            playDeck.addAll(cards);
            Collections.shuffle(playDeck);
        }

        public Card pop() {
            if (playDeck.isEmpty()) {
                return null;
            }
            return playDeck.remove(0);
        }

        public void push(Card card) {
            playDeck.add(card);
        }

    }

    enum Face {
        ONE("1"), TWO("2"), THREE("3"), FOUR("4"), FIVE("5"), SIX("6"), SEVEN("7"), EIGHT("8"), NINE("9"), JACK("J"), QUEEN("Q"), KING("K");

        private String value;

        private Face(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        private static Face[] items = new Face[]{
            ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, JACK, QUEEN, KING
        };
    }

    enum Suit {
        CLUBS("♣"), DIAMONDS("♦"), HEARTS("♥"), SPADES("♠");

        private String value;

        private Suit(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public static Suit[] items = new Suit[]{
            CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES
        };
    }

    public class GamePane extends JPanel {

        private List<Hand> players;

        private Map<Card, Rectangle> mapCards;

        private Card selected;

        public GamePane(List<Hand> players) {
            this.players = players;
            mapCards = new HashMap<>(players.size() * 5);

            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (selected != null) {
                        Rectangle bounds = mapCards.get(selected);
                        bounds.y += 20;
                        repaint();
                    }
                    selected = null;
                    // This is done backwards, as the last card is on
                    // top.  Of course you could render the cards
                    // in reverse order, but you get the idea
                    for (Card card : players.get(0).reveresed()) {
                        Rectangle bounds = mapCards.get(card);
                        if (bounds.contains(e.getPoint())) {
                            selected = card;
                            bounds.y -= 20;
                            repaint();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        @Override
        public void invalidate() {
            super.invalidate();
            mapCards.clear();
            Hand hand = players.get(0);
            int cardHeight = (getHeight() - 20) / 3;
            int cardWidth = (int) (cardHeight * 0.6);
            int xDelta = cardWidth / 2;
            int xPos = (int) ((getWidth() / 2) - (cardWidth * (hand.size() / 4.0)));
            int yPos = (getHeight() - 20) - cardHeight;
            for (Card card : hand.cards()) {
                Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(xPos, yPos, cardWidth, cardHeight);
                mapCards.put(card, bounds);
                xPos += xDelta;
            }
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            Hand hand = players.get(0);
            for (Card card : hand.cards) {
                Rectangle bounds = mapCards.get(card);
                System.out.println(bounds);
                if (bounds != null) {
                    g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    g2d.fill(bounds);
                    g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    g2d.draw(bounds);
                    Graphics2D copy = (Graphics2D) g2d.create();
                    paintCard(copy, card, bounds);
                    copy.dispose();
                }
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        protected void paintCard(Graphics2D g2d, Card card, Rectangle bounds) {
            g2d.translate(bounds.x + 5, bounds.y + 5);
            g2d.setClip(0, 0, bounds.width - 5, bounds.height - 5);

            String text = card.getFace().getValue() + card.getSuit().getValue();
            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();

            g2d.drawString(text, 0, fm.getAscent());
        }
    }

}
```

> Although I can't seem to understand the part inside invalidate() method, more especially the coordinates. Could you put an explanation on why you have done such formulas and how can I come up with my own? Thanks in advance

Start by getting a piece of paper, draw a rectangle representing the screen and then draw the cards the way you want them laid out - seriously, for any suitably complex UI, I always start with a piece of paper, you can scribble ideas, perform calculations, perform walk throughs, basically, focus your intent - and discard a lot of things that don't work.  I've even been known to use cutouts

`invalidate` is called when ever the component's size or position changes. You could also use a `ComponentListener`, I just took the easiest route (just beware, I'm also been lazy, `invalidate` can be called a number of times in quick succession)

First, we need to know how tall a card is going to be, from this we can calculate the width as a ratio of the height

```
int cardHeight = (getHeight() - 20) / 3;
int cardWidth = (int) (cardHeight * 0.6);
```

You could spend some time working out an algorithm which ensures that the cards are always displayed (ie calculate the height/width of the card based on smallest of the components height/width, but I went for easy) - This means, if the component's width is reduced enough, the cards will overflow the available space.

Next, we need to determine by how much each card is offset from the previous...

```
int xDelta = cardWidth / 2;
```

In this case, each card will overlap the second by half

Next, we need to calculate the starting position of the first card...

```
int xPos = (int) ((getWidth() / 2) - (cardWidth * (hand.size() / 4.0)));
```

`(getWidth() / 2)` calculates the horizontal centre position of the component, this will ensure that the cards are laid out around the horizontal centre of the component.

`(cardWidth * (hand.size() / 4.0)` basically calculates the over all width required to laid out all the cards and divides it in half, as half will appear to the left of the horizontal centre and the other half to the right.  Okay, I realise that might not make sense, but remember, each card is overlapping the previous by half it's width, so, we can't divide by 2, we need to divide it by 4 (2 x 2).

So, `cardWidth * hand.size()` will provide the total width of all the cards laid out side by side. `(cardWidth * hand.size()) / 2` provides (obviously) half that amount, which can be used as a bases for the origin point of the first card, when subtracted from the horizontal centre.  `((cardWidth * hand.size()) / 2) / 2` will allow for the cards to overlapped by half their width.

Lastly, we calculate the vertical origin point of the cards...

```
int yPos = (getHeight() - 20) - cardHeight;
```

That's pretty easy and self explanatory.

In the loop, as we calculate the position of each card, we offset the next card by the `xDelta`

```
xPos += xDelta;
```

which, obviously, gives us the horizontal position of the next card

Comment: "can't have them connected" I should have said I can't seem to have them connected as I could't figure out a way, but you helped me a lot and this is totally what I was searching for. Although I can't seem to understand the part inside invalidate() method, more especially the coordinates. Could you put an explanation on why you have done such formulas and how can I come up with my own? Thanks in advance